# Flutter ReorderableListView flashes when reorder firebase documents

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting documents from firebase in my flutter app. I am using a ReorderableListView in an stream builder. But when I reorder the items it jumps to its current position and then to its new position. I am sorting it by a field called 'position' from the firebase document.

It looks like this:

[image]

I am using this code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: AppTheme.background,
    body: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 50),
            child: SizedBox(
                child:
                    NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
                        onNotification: (overscroll) {
                          overscroll.disallowIndicator();
                          return false;
                        },
                        child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection(widget.user!.uid)
                                .orderBy("position", descending: false)
                                .snapshots(),
                            builder: (BuildContext context,
                                AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                return const Center(
                                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                                ));
                              }
                              if (snapshot.hasData &&
                                  snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {}
                              List<String> listElement = [];
                              snapshot.data!.docs.map<List>((f) {
                                String name = ' ';

                                Map<String, dynamic> data =
                                    f.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                                data.forEach((a, b) {
                                  name = f.id;
                                  listElement.add(name);
                                });
                                return listElement;
                              }).toList();
                              return Theme(
                                  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                                    canvasColor: Colors.transparent,
                                    shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
                                  ),
                                  child: ReorderableListView(
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                                      if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
                                        newIndex -= 1;
                                      }

                                      var arr =
                                          listElement.toSet().toList();
                                      final tile = arr.removeAt(oldIndex);
                                      arr.insert(newIndex, tile);
                                      for (var name in arr) {
                                        FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                            .collection(widget.user!.uid)
                                            .doc(name)
                                            .update({
                                          "position": arr.indexOf(name)
                                        });
                                      }
                                    },
                                    children: getExpenseItems(snapshot),
                                  ));
                            })))),
      ],
    ));
  }
```

Does anyone know what I can do to solve this issue?